# Input type file accept only one type of application without allFiles option

Tags: javascript, input

Hello I have an input with type file which should accept solely zipped files  `<input type="file" accept=".zip"/>` But when I click apart from compressed zippes I have also option 'AllFiles' is there any way to get rid of it in windows? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is controlled by the operating system and cannot be changed from the browser. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/accept):

> The accept attribute doesn't validate the types of the selected files; it simply provides hints for browsers to guide users towards selecting the correct file types. It is still possible (in most cases) for users to toggle an option in the file chooser that makes it possible to override this and select any file they wish, and then choose incorrect file types.
> Because of this, you should make sure that expected requirement is validated server-side.